# C++ - Adding Spaces to String

Tags: c++, string, parsing, substr

Hey so I am trying to write a simple program that adds spaces to a given string that has none in C++ here is the code I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string AddSpaceToString (string input)
{
    const int arrLength = 5;
    int lastFind = 0;
    string output;
    string dictionary[arrLength] = {"hello", "hey", "whats", "up", "man"};

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrLength; j++)
        {
            if(dictionary[j] == input.substr(lastFind, i))
            {
                lastFind = i;
                output += dictionary[j] + " ";
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}

int main ()
{
    cout << AddSpaceToString("heywhatshelloman") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason the output only gives `hey whats` and then stops.  What is going on I can't seem to make this very simple code work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading `"hey"` and `"whats"`, the value of `i` is more than the length of `"hello"` and hence no such substring exists for the code `input.substr(lastFind, i)`.

You should check for the length of possible substring (`dictionary[j]`) and not `i`.

```
input.substr( lastFind, dictionary[j].size() )
```

Also you will have to change:

```
lastFind += dictionary[j].size();
```

So the if loop becomes:

```
if(dictionary[j] == input.substr(lastFind, dictionary[j].size() ))
            {
                lastFind += dictionary[j].size();
                output += dictionary[j] + " ";
            }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution, I was under the assumption the `substr()` function's first parameter was the start position of the string and the second was the end position where in reality its the start position and the length.  Thanks for the help I got it to work with your answer @AbhishekBansal

Answer (score 1):

this works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string AddSpaceToString (string input)
{
    const int arrLength = 5;
    unsigned int lastFind = 0;
    string output;
    string dictionary[arrLength] = {"hello", "hey", "whats", "up", "man"};

    for (int j = 0; lastFind < input.size() && j < arrLength; ++j)
    {       

         if(dictionary[j] == input.substr(lastFind, dictionary[j].size()))
         {
            lastFind += dictionary[j].size();
            output += dictionary[j] + " ";
            j = -1;
         }
    }

    return output;
}

int main ()
{
    cout << AddSpaceToString("heywhatshelloman") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice getting rid of the second loop much more efficient O(N) nice! is it tested? @Julius